# android studio Arctic Fox 2021.3.1 doesn't show #signing report in gradle bar | #SHA1 Not Showing Problem Solved

Tags: android, gradle, sha1

I'm starting a new project using Firebase and I have to get an SHA1 key from my project. Recently I've updated Android Studio to version Arctic Fox 2021.3.1 and the signing report tab disappeared from the Gradle bar.

Answer (score 2):

> Go -> Settings  -> Experimental  -> uncheck to -Do not build Gradle
> task list during Gradle Sync.   -> Apply
>
> -> Sync Project with Gradle Files